# How to increases the CPU usage of my Python program?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a program in Raspberry Pi 3 to read the inputs using an MCP3008 ADC from a function generator. I want to read two channels at the same time and then write it to a file. When I have just one channel, I get about 12000 samples per second, however, when I have two channels, I get about 6000 samples per second for each channel. To get 12000 samples per second for each channels, I tried to write two different scripts, one for each channel and then run them simultaneously in two different terminals. However, that does not solve the problem and gives me 6000 samples per second for each channel.

When I have just one script, I get about 9% CPU usage. When I run two scripts at the same time in two different terminals, I get about 5% CPU usage for each process. How do I get each process to use 9% CPU each or higher?

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import spidev, time, os

# opens SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)

#spi1 = spidev.SpiDev()
#spi1.open(0, 1)

ch0 = 0
#ch1 = 1

now = time.time() * 1000
data = open("test_plot.dat", "w")
#data1 = open("test_plot_1.dat", "w")

def getReading(channel):
    # pull raw data from chip
    rawData = spi.xfer([1, (8 + channel) << 4, 0])
    # process raw data to something we understand
    processedData = ((rawData[1]&3) << 8) + rawData[2]
    return processedData
"""
def getReading1(channel):
    # pull raw data from chip
    rawData = spi1.xfer([1, (8 + channel) << 4, 0])
    # process raw data to something we understand
    processedData = ((rawData[1]&3) << 8) + rawData[2]
    return processedData
"""
while True:
    if (((time.time() * 1000) - now) < 10001):
        data.write("%d\n" % getReading(ch0))
        #data1.write("%d\n" % getReading1(ch1))
    else:
        break

# http://www.takaitra.com/posts/492
```

Comment: Are you sure the limit you are hitting is CPU bound?

Comment: To get more CPU usage you can add a for loop doing garbage. That will sure make things better

Comment: I think so. Because the ADC MCP3008 can go upto 200 kHz with 5V and 75 kHz with 3.3V. I am using 3.3V so it should, in theory be able to get to 75 kHz.

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie For loop doing garbage? How?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi Just trying to make a point that it is not the end result you wish for. What to meant to ask is how to get better sample rate, and just give the CPU usage you get as data to consider.

Comment: If you're cpu-bound and you're in python, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: Did you try to remove time checking and see what it does to performance? Maybe checking the time so much increases "read cycle" latency.

Comment: I did `gc.collect()` for every loop that I ran and it decreased the samples per second exponentially. I will try to remove the time checking, thank you.

Comment: Removing the time check does absolutely nothing to the number of samples I get per second.

Comment: Do you think that using multiprocessing will be any different from just running two scripts simultaneously?

Comment: what speed is your SPI clock at? That's probably what limiting you here

Comment: Usually, if a single thread/process uses only 9% CPU, this indicates that the task is not CPU bound (else, you would see more CPU usage). Multiprocessing essentially is the same as "starting two scripts", but programmatically, not manually. The usual use case is when you have a task that uses nearly 100% of one CPU core and which can be split up to be done in parallel.

Comment: I guess you know about [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md) and [that](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008) - check for latency etc. Have you tried for example [spidev_test](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c)?

Comment: I have not set the speed of my clock yet. The default value is 0, however, when I set it to some arbritary value like 900000, it gives me more samples (instead of 10,000/second, it gives me like 50,000/second), but it gets rid of some data points. So instead of seeing a nice sine wave, I see gaps in between.

Comment: @spidev_test ARe you saying that I should just go ahead and use C?

Comment: I tried the Adafruit's library but it's much slower. Instead of 10,000 samples per second that I am getting with the spi-device library now, I get about 2,000 samples per second.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi in the datasheet, it says at 2.7V the max clock frequency in 1.35MHx, try that and see how many samples/second you get. If you need more, try running the MCP3008 with 5V

Comment: It looks like each read takes 24 clock cycles. Assuming continuous reading at 1.35MHz, this should get you at most 56250 samples. But you aren't continuously reading, you also are writting data to a file, so expect a bit below this. Multi threading this wont make a difference, you are at the MCP3008 max frequency. If you need more samples per second, run it at 5V and you can go to 3.6MHz.

Comment: @jacoblaw I was running my script at 3.3V. When I changed it to 5V, it changed nothing. So I think that we are limited by the Python script and not the ADC.

Comment: So you powered the chip with 5V and then you changed your SPI clock to what frequency?

Comment: I left it at the default value of 0, is that an issue?

Comment: What should I change it to? 200,000 because that's the maximum frequency that the ADC can operate at?

Comment: Yes, that's an issue. Put it to 3.6MHz if the chip is running at 5V and see how many samples/second you get

Comment: @jacoblaw Awesome! Thank you so much, I am now getting 33,000 samples/second as opposed to about 10,000 samples/second. How do I go faster? I think that the very act of outputting the data is taking some time. Is there a way to make that faster? I tried the print statement, sys.stdout.write, but they were much slower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150124/discussion-between-jacoblaw-and-akshat-tripathi).